# How to count occurances of special character in a string in mongodb using springboot?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

In a mongo collection there are around 120k documents. For each document I have to check  how many occurrences of special character '@' is in message field.

Below is the document in json format

```
[{
"_id":356,
"message":"ty@78i@gh8"
}]
```

If it contains more than 2 @. I will perform some java function.
I tried the below solution --

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $project: { 
          _id: 0, 
          message: 1, 
          count: { 
              $subtract: [ 
                  { $size: { $split: [ "$message", "@" ] } }, 1 
              ] 
          } 
      } 
  }
] )
```

Java equavilent code --

```
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id",0).append(message, 1)
          .append(count, new BasicDBObject("$submit", new BasicDBObject("size", 
           new BasicDBObject("$split", "$messgae").append(@))));
```

Java equivalent code is actually incomplete because I don't know how can I aggregate and then traverse for each document.

Comment: your solution seems do the task as expected: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3zZlDuziWKZ

Comment: Oh okay but can you please check the equivalent java code.

Comment: And just one more thing @R2D2 although it's working here. When I tried it with my collection. I got this error -- The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type:null

Comment: The null error is happening when you are missing "message" filed in some of the documents , adding ifNull will eliminate this problem: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3o1YtVt2EQp

Comment: But you need to translate this to Java  , it is not my area :( ...